# SAPUI5 Busy Indicator for ui.Table with manifest.json datasource

Tags: sapui5, manifest.json

```
manifest.json entry
---------------------
"sap.ui5": {
    "models": {
        "": {
            "dataSource": "Main",
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel"
        },

Page1.view.xml entry
---------------------
<Table id="Table1"
    busy="true"
    rows="{/Rowsets/Rowset/0/Row}">
```

---

Hi, I am trying to understand how best to use Busy Indicator.
App loads a table (sap.ui.table.table) in Page1 from a manifest.json dataSource.
I want to show table busy until the dataSource completes and the table is loaded.

Should I set 'busy' in Controller, instead of the View? (see above View example.)

I have seen many examples and tried to use the DemoKit with no success.  Tried this with no success:

```
this.byId("Table1").setBusy(false);
```

Where should code be located to start/show busy, know the table is loaded, and then stop,hide,end the busy indicator?
Not sure if I should use
`setBusy()` or `hide.`

---

Thanks much for your thoughts.

Comment: JSONModel is a client side model which is typically used with client data at runtime (e.g. UI states). What kind of data source does the `"Main"` address? Is it actually an OData service?

Comment: Not oData.  SQL Server query returned as  JSON or XML.

Comment: Remember that all views and controls also have the property `busyIndicatorDelay` which is 1000 (millisec) by default. If you want to see the busy state immediately you should set the delay to 0 (`<Table busyIndicatorDelay="0" ... />`)

Comment: I'll try busyIndicatorDelay.  Thanks for your thoughts.